# Extra white space in ASCII file due to Translate GDAL from QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdal-translate, ascii, qgis-modeler

Could anyone enlighten me why do I get an extra white space in from of my first column in an ASCII file generated through a model? With ArcGIS it doesn't happen.

Output raster type: Int32
Output size: 100.0
Output size is a percentage of input size: Yes

I'm not really sure what extra information should I provide, so if you can by a comment tell what parameter you need to see/know etc.

EDIT: Problem is with the the header files they are too far to the left. I found this out since I'm using a script to process the ASCII file. If I add space to each one, it solves the problem, but it won't help me much since I have quite a lot to fix them.

An example of header from one of my ASCII's (They all have the same specs):

```
ncols        1233
nrows        1165
xllcorner    989098.010305976960
yllcorner    6389026.025735749900
dx           10.003277779965
dy           10.002517682335
NODATA_value -9999
```

Comment: Please convert the content in your comments to question body then delete the comments. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with leading whitespace.

Comment: Is it White or NoData? Do you currently have a NoData value in the ASCII file? (show header rows in your question please and perhaps the first two or three lines truncated).. this will answer these questions and a few more. It could be because of the cell assignment, some software uses upper left, others centre centre (Esri can use either).. you might get better results if you converted them in Esri to GeoTiff or ERDAS img files before using your QGIS model.

Comment: Removing the data sample did significant harm to the quality of this question.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson, I didn't thought of that as it seems like a lot of work going to ArcGIS converting the shapes to Geotiff then adding it to the model. My model takes in vector shapefiles, changes them into a raster, then into an ASCII as I really need the last format. Currently, data values are: NoData -9999 and the rest simple integers from 0 to 9.

Comment: If the data would fit in a single character (2 with whitespace), then using a "-9999" nodata value is seriously wasteful -- what's wrong with "-9", which would use half the space?

Comment: @Vince I use -9999 for floating point rasters as this value is unlikely to be ever seen as a real value (other values I've encountered are 29,999 and float.MinValue)... ASCII itself is a wasteful format (character strings for numbers - BAH!) that format isn't truly Esri compliant (see http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/GP_ToolRef/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm) which is why I say keep them TIFF until they get into Esri and use Esri to convert to ASCII as required (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000005000000)

Comment: Thank you guys, those are pretty interesting comments, and you do have a point, Vince. I might as well use a -9 but "-9999" is a pretty standard NoData value, good enough to get ignored so I didn't bothered as much. Yet, I really don't believe that is the problem as other data which I tested work fine (ASCII made with ArcGIS ModelBuilder). Well, indeed, ASCII isn't the best but the problem comes when my script in Python which makes the calculations can only take ASCII as input.

Comment: In any case, I'm looking to solve this using an open source approach, which is why I used GDAL. Just now I placed some of my vector data in ArcGIS to obtain the desired ASCII files, and both headers and leads are lined up nicely. This is really odd.

Comment: How does one place put the FORCE_CELLSIZE=YES into use? I've tried adding it to the small additional parameters box but I receive an error.